# Visual Studio - automatically implement all inherited methods from an interface

Tags: visual-studio-2008, inheritance, interface

Let's say we have a class called MyClass.

```
public class MyClass
```

We also have an interface like so:

```
public interface MyInterface{

public string SomeFunction(int foo, string bar, short baz){}
}
```

We want this class to inherit from MyInterface.

```
public class MyClass: MyInterface
```

MyInterface has *n* properties, and *i* methods. How can I get Visual Studio to automatically implement all those methods and properties without the developer doing any of the legwork?

Comment: With automatically implement you mean adding the function signatures?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For C#, you can right click the 'MyInterface' and choose 'Implement Interface' from the context menu. I believe there is a similar (but slightly different) shortcut for VB.NET.

Comment: In VB.NET, when you type a carriage return after "Implements MyInterface", Visual Studio automagically adds stubs for all the un-implemented members.

Comment: Or the otherway around start writing the implementation and extract the Interface from the class.... You have it as an Refactor option in 2008 ....

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use shortcut "CTR+." to do that. Position your cursor on MyInterface of "public class MyClass: MyInterface" line, and press "CTR+.", a context menu will show up with "Implement Interface ...".

Answer (score 3):

To automatically implement all inherited methods from an interface:

C# : Just right click on interface(Prefix with 'I') name and select implement interface option.

VB.NET : Just point your cursor after interface(Prefix with 'I') name and hit enter.

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for macros in Visual Studio.  [Here is an example that does a similar thing for abstract classes.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/abstractimplementation.aspx)  It should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Harper's answer is much better, note that it requires VS 2008.  My current project is at a VS 2005 client, hence my macro solution...

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013 you can right click on the interface and select "Implement Interface". It will generate all the methods for you with the NotImplmentedException.

Answer (score 0):

On VS2022, you can go to one of the classes that implements your interface, then click "CTRL + ." on the interface (where the error occurs), then apply "Implement interface" to the whole project/solution. This option is shown after "Fix all occurrences in:". [Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpAyg.png)